_appwrite.default is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes shows this error
I am working with app write first time but it shows error during the auth user (signup) so here what is the problem?
import { Account, Client, ID } from 'react-native-appwrite';
export const config = {
    endPoint: "https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1",
    platform: 'xyx',
    projectId: 'xyx',
    databaseId: 'xyx',
    userCollectionId: 'xyx',
    videoCollectionId: 'xyx',
    storageId: 'xyx'
}

const client = new Client();

client
    .setEndpoint(config.endPoint)
    .setProject(config.projectId)
    .setPlatform(config.platform)
    ;

const account = new Account(client);

export const CreateUser = () => {
    account.create(ID.unique(), 'me@example.com', 'password', 'Jane Doe')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}


Check the file you imported the createUser function in... The import statement should look like this:
import { createUser } from ""; 

and not like this :
import createUser from ""; 


when makiing your import do
import {funcName} from '{_path_to_appwrite.js}'
